# "Additional Contributions" section is required: why?

Tags: civicontribute, contributions, contribution-page

The real question here is how to make it optional. Off the top of my head: make "No Thank You" option selected/default choice with a grain of JavaScript. Or https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_buildForm/  - however the latter feels a bit of overhead.

**Note**
Cheers @petednz-fuzion

So there is a "Membership" section enabled and  "Contribution Amounts section enabled" without Price set so "Fixed Contribution Options" is being used  and "Allow other amounts" also.

[image: This is how]

Comment: I can't picture what you are referring to. eg do you see 'additional contribution' at https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/admin/contribute/settings?reset=1&action=update&id=1&selectedChild=amount

Comment: @petednz-fuzion Right, sorry, it is more complex indeed. So there is a "Membership" section enabled and  "Contribution Amounts section enabled" without Price set so "Fixed Contribution Options" is being used  and "Allow other amounts" also. Have edited the initial notes.

Comment: why not just use a Price Set?

Comment: @petednz-fuzion Would a Price Set usage eliminate Additional Contribution Required attribute? Why is it Required at all?

Comment: Additional Contribution pre-dated Price Sets. And i don't know which version of 'required' you mean. THe system does not 'require' it, but the system can 'require' it of the user (ie they 'must' add an additional contribution. I think Price Sets are what you need to look at using

Comment: Decided to give this an Answer - ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the solution you are looking for is available via Price Sets

Comment: Thank you, accepting the answer even if not quite sure re: the logic behind this.